# jquery mobile 1.1.1 - Collpasible strange behavior

Tags: jquery-mobile

Collapsibles are not working as espected in the JQM 1.1.1.

For example, trying to reproduce the examples in this page:

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/lists-collapsible.html (Non-inset, individual collapsibles), with the collapsible fitting all page and squared corners. If I use the previous version 1.1.0, everything work as espected.

The example below also have an uncespected behavior - the list divider is painted over the collpasible header.

```
<div data-role="page" id="home_page">
<div data-role="header">
<h1>Phonegap App</h1>
</div> <!-- /header -->
<div data-role="content">
<div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="true" 
data-collapsed="false" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="d">
<h3>More in this section</h3>
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="d">
<li data-role="list-divider">Pages &amp; Dialogs</li>
<li><a href="page-anatomy.html">Anatomy of a page</a></li>
<li><a href="page-links.html">Linking pages</a></li>
<li><a href="page-transitions.html">Page transitions</a></li>
<li><a href="loader.html">Page loading widget</a></li>
<li><a href="page-dialogs.html">Dialogs</a></li>
<li><a href="popup/index.html">Popups</a></li>
<li class="ui-corner-bottom"><a href="pages-themes.html">Theming pages</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

Using jquery.mobile-1.1.1.css jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js jquery-1.7.2.min.js

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue or not, but the link you posted is for the 1.2 alpha build, not 1.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That appears to be a bug, here's a quick CSS fix:

```
​.ui-listview .ui-li-divider {
    margin : 5px -1px 0 -1px;
}​
```

I noticed a while ago that when elements overlap in jQuery Mobile sites, you can usually fix it with some margin tweaking.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JYN76/